# what's the difference between class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct and when to use each one?

Tags: c#

I'm not trying to save my research time. I already read about some majors differences between them.

But I was hoping to get a summary or the best clarification about the differences and when to use each one from only one person point of view

I've done some researches but still, I'm comparing between two things and each one of them is reviewed by totally two different guys!

*I think it will benefit a lot of people .. Thank you for your time =)!*

Comment: You will need several books about C# class design and architecture to fully answer this question. Way too broad.

Comment: What does this have to do with asp.net? And I agree with Oded - it's way too broad a question to answer sensibly.

Comment: MSDN has some good online material for learning the language basics: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336768.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx

Comment: @John .. I'm building an n-layered web applications with asp.net so I I just placed the tag so if anyone had a specific advice when building web application he would share it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to Oded and Jon - here's the best way to save research time: [Teach yourself C# in 24 hours](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672331012).

Or [here's a list from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336795).

Comment: I didn't know that it's this broad, I thought for example you'll say class : reference type, mostly used to ... and struct is a value type and mostly used to define your own data types! .. anyway thank you Andras (Y):)

Comment: @Ikashef - no probs - and I applaud you for reacting so well to your question being closed; I hope you've nevertheless been able to get something out of it! :)